# Flutter - how can I add the button to Paste selected text in textfield?

Tags: flutter, button, textfield, copy-paste

I want to implement button, by clicking that button I want to **paste** the select text (From any source Exp - from the message app) into the textfield. We have a plugin for make a button to copy the text, do we have anything similar to paste the text.

Comment: Can you please clarify where to add the button? I mean the position whether it should place on actionBar or somwhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text you want to select is from the same app, you can achieve this using Clipboard

```
TextEditingController textFieldController = new TextEditingController();
Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: "copied text")); // copy text

onPressed() async { // onPress function of button
  ClipboardData data = await Clipboard.getData('text/plain');
  setState(() {
    textFieldController.text = data.text.toString(); // this will paste "copied text" to textFieldController
  });
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Pasting worked for me also for content from other Apps.